# Julia | DataFrame | Replacing missing Values

Tags: dataframe, julia

How can we replace `missing` values with `0.0` for a column in a `DataFrame`?

Comment: don't like `df[:B]=convert(Array,df[:B],0.0)` ?

Comment: @RezaAfzalan I tried using this approach but when I run `convert(Array,df_of_names,"none")` it gives an error saying `MethodError: no method matching convert(::Type{Array}, ::DataFrames.DataFrame, ::String)`. Running `convert(Array,df_of_names)` works fine though. Do have any idea why it could be giving that error?

Answer (score 18):

There are a few different approaches to this problem (valid for Julia 1.x):

### Base.replace!

Probably the easiest approach is to use `replace!` or `replace` from base Julia. Here is an example with `replace!`:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(x = [1, missing, 3])
3×1 DataFrame
│ Row │ x       │
│     │ Int64⍰  │
├─────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ 1       │
│ 2   │ missing │
│ 3   │ 3       │

julia> replace!(df.x, missing => 0);

julia> df
3×1 DataFrame
│ Row │ x      │
│     │ Int64⍰ │
├─────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ 1      │
│ 2   │ 0      │
│ 3   │ 3      │
```

However, note that at this point the type of column `x` still allows missing values:

```
julia> typeof(df.x)
Array{Union{Missing, Int64},1}
```

This is also indicated by the question mark following `Int64` in column `x` when the data frame is printed out. You can change this by using `disallowmissing!` ([from the DataFrames.jl package)](http://juliadata.github.io/DataFrames.jl/stable/lib/functions/#DataFrames.disallowmissing!):

```
julia> disallowmissing!(df, :x)
3×1 DataFrame
│ Row │ x     │
│     │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │
│ 2   │ 0     │
│ 3   │ 3     │
```

Alternatively, if you use `replace` (without the exclamation mark) as follows, then the output will already disallow missing values:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(x = [1, missing, 3]);

julia> df.x = replace(df.x, missing => 0);

julia> df
3×1 DataFrame
│ Row │ x     │
│     │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │
│ 2   │ 0     │
│ 3   │ 3     │
```

Finally, you can replace `missing` in all columns at once by using `mapcols`:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(a=[1, missing, 3], b=[4, 5, missing]);

julia> mapcols(col -> replace(col, missing => 0), df)
3×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b     
     │ Int64  Int64 
─────┼──────────────
   1 │     1      4
   2 │     0      5
   3 │     3      0
```

### Base.ismissing with logical indexing

You can use `ismissing` with logical indexing to assign a new value to all missing entries of an array:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(x = [1, missing, 3]);

julia> df.x[ismissing.(df.x)] .= 0;

julia> df
3×1 DataFrame
│ Row │ x      │
│     │ Int64⍰ │
├─────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ 1      │
│ 2   │ 0      │
│ 3   │ 3      │
```

### Base.coalesce

Another approach is to use `coalesce`:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(x = [1, missing, 3]);

julia> df.x = coalesce.(df.x, 0);

julia> df
3×1 DataFrame
│ Row │ x     │
│     │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │
│ 2   │ 0     │
│ 3   │ 3     │
```

### DataFramesMeta

Both `replace` and `coalesce` can be used with the `@transform` macro from the [DataFramesMeta.jl](https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFramesMeta.jl) package:

```
julia> using DataFramesMeta

julia> df = DataFrame(x = [1, missing, 3]);

julia> @transform(df, x = replace(:x, missing => 0))
3×1 DataFrame
│ Row │ x     │
│     │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │
│ 2   │ 0     │
│ 3   │ 3     │
```

```
julia> df = DataFrame(x = [1, missing, 3]);

julia> @transform(df, x = coalesce.(:x, 0))
3×1 DataFrame
│ Row │ x     │
│     │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │
│ 2   │ 0     │
│ 3   │ 3     │
```

### Additional documentation

- [Julia manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/missing/)
- [Julia manual - function reference](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Missing-Values-1)
- [DataFrames.jl manual](http://juliadata.github.io/DataFrames.jl/stable/man/missing/)

Comment: Is there a way to replace missing simultaneously in all columns of the dataframe?

Comment: @fact You can use `mapcols`. I added an example of that to the answer above.

Answer (score 2):

create `df` with some `NA`s

```
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame(A = 1.0:10.0, B = 2.0:2.0:20.0)
df[ df[:B] %2 .== 0, :A ] = NA
```

you'll see some `NA` in `df`... we now convert them to 0.0

```
df[ isna(df[:A]), :A] = 0
```

EDIT=`NaN`→`NA`. Thanks @Reza

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are pretty good all over. If you are a real speed junky, perhaps the following might be for you:

```
# prepare example
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame(A = 1.0:10.0, B = 2.0:2.0:20.0)
df[ df[:A] %2 .== 0, :B ] = NA


df[:B].data[df[:B].na] = 0.0 # put the 0.0 into NAs
df[:B] = df[:B].data         # with no NAs might as well use array
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a shorter and more updated answer since Julia introduced the `missing` attribute recently.

```
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame(A=rand(1:50, 5), B=rand(1:50, 5), C=vcat(rand(1:50,3), missing, rand(1:50))) ## Creating random 5 integers within the range of 1:50, while introducing a missing variable in one of the rows
df = DataFrame(replace!(convert(Matrix, df), missing=>0)) ## Converting to matrix first, since replacing values directly within type dataframe is not allowed
```

Comment: This answer is great if all columns of the `DataFrame` have the same type. If this is not the case, you will lose all type informations and every column has type `Any`.