# DataFrame.jl missing imputation (Julia Programming Language)

Tags: julia

How should I perform missing imputation in DataFrame.jl?
E.g., for a given DataFrame, how to turn all missings to 0. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just walk over to Bogumil's office and ask him :)

Comment: If I am to answer the question anyway it is better to have the answer recorded on SO for the future :).

Comment: [Here's a closely related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34611109/julia-dataframe-replacing-missing-values)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `coalesce` and broadcasting. So assuming your data frame is stored in `df` variable then just do:

```
df .= coalesce.(df, 0)
```

Now, if you wanted to perform this substitution only in selected columns then do:

```
@. df[!, cols] = coalesce(df[!, cols], 0)
```

where `cols` is a column selector.

An alternative way to achieve this is to use `transform!`:

```
transform!(df, cols .=> ByRow(x -> coalesce(x, 0)), renamecols=false)
```

where `cols` is your column selector. Use `names(df)` for `cols` is you want to do the imputation in all columns of the `DataFrame`.

This approach is a bit more verbose in this case, but it is more flexible in general.