# How to replacing missing values in a julia Pipe

Tags: dataframe, julia

I want to replace missing values in a pipe. I'm aware of how to do it outside a pipe [(see this
post for more on that)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34611109/julia-dataframe-replacing-missing-values).

```
julia> df = DataFrame(:b => [2, 3], :a => [missing, "treatment"])
2×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ b     │ a         │
│     │ Int64 │ String?   │
├─────┼───────┼───────────┤
│ 1   │ 2     │ missing   │
│ 2   │ 3     │ treatment │

julia> df.a = replace(df.a, missing => "control")  # works like expected


julia> @pipe df |>
             replace(_.a, missing => "control") |>
             select(_, :a, :b) # error because replace doesn't return a DataFrame.
```

I tried writing a transformation function but `ismissing()` doesn't work in this context. I assume this is because it get's handed a column an not the separate values. But `ismissing.()` doesn't work either. Does somebody have an idea how I can make this transformation work?

```
julia> ismissing(df.a[1])
true

julia> @pipe df |>
             DataFrames.transform(_, :a => x -> ismissing(x) ? "control" : x)
2×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ b     │ a         │ a_function │
│     │ Int64 │ String?   │ String?    │
├─────┼───────┼───────────┼────────────┤
│ 1   │ 2     │ missing   │ missing    │
│ 2   │ 3     │ treatment │ treatment  │

julia> @pipe df |>
             DataFrames.transform(_, :a => x -> ismissing(x) ? x : "control" )
2×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ b     │ a         │ a_function │
│     │ Int64 │ String?   │ String     │
├─────┼───────┼───────────┼────────────┤
│ 1   │ 2     │ missing   │ control    │
│ 2   │ 3     │ treatment │ control    │

julia> @pipe df |>
             DataFrames.transform(_, :a => (x -> ismissing.(x) ? "control" : x) )
ERROR: TypeError: non-boolean (BitArray{1}) used in boolean context
```

P.s.
I know I can use the `@transform` macro, but I don't find it very elegant. I think this replacement should be possible in one line of code.

```
julia> @pipe df |>
             @transform(_, :a, x = replace(:a, missing => "control")) |>
             select(_, Not(:a)) |>
             rename(_, :x => :a)
2×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ b     │ a         │
│     │ Int64 │ String    │
├─────┼───────┼───────────┤
│ 1   │ 2     │ control   │
│ 2   │ 3     │ treatment │
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are four sample ways to do it.

```
julia> @pipe df |>
             select(_, :a => ByRow(x -> coalesce(x, "control")) => :a, :b)
2×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a          b
     │ String     Int64
─────┼──────────────────
   1 │ control        2
   2 │ treatment      3

julia> @pipe df |>
             select(_, :a => (x -> coalesce.(x, "control")) => :a, :b)
2×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a          b
     │ String     Int64
─────┼──────────────────
   1 │ control        2
   2 │ treatment      3

julia> @pipe df |>
             select(_, :a => (x -> replace(x, missing => "control")) => :a, :b)
2×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a          b
     │ String     Int64
─────┼──────────────────
   1 │ control        2
   2 │ treatment      3

julia> @pipe df |>
             select(_, :a => ByRow(x -> ismissing(x) ? "control" : x) => :a, :b)
2×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a          b
     │ String     Int64
─────┼──────────────────
   1 │ control        2
   2 │ treatment      3
```